# Read screen on iPhone

Tags: ios, pdf

Read screen feature on iPhone is great.

However it is not so easy to use in a sense that you can make it read anything, anywhere. For example, one had better download a PDF file to make it recognize texts better than online. Then for a large PDF file, it keeps reading until it stops somewhere automatically by itself.

How to control the read screen feature so that it can read from page *a* to *b* controlled by the user? And it seems that it can't recognize texts from a picture format?